# Is jQuery UI tabs broken in rc6?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using jQuery UI v1.6rc2 for a while, and wanted to upgrade to 1.6rc6 to see that they haven't made any breaking changes. It seems they have; all of my tabs stop working whenever I switch to rc6.

There seems to be two things wrong. First, the manual advocates using the following:

```
$('#container').tabs();
```

However, with rc2 I've always had to do this:

```
$('#container > ul').tabs();
```

So when rc6 is in effect, none of these methods work.

Also, Firebug reports the following error when rc6 is installed:

```
$.Event is not a function.
this.namespace+'-state-disabled').attr("...event[prop]=event.originalEvent[prop];}}
```

All Javascript/jQuery executed before the call to .tabs() work fine. It breaks in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to jQuery core version 1.3.1
UI 1.6rc6 only works with 1.3.1

Comment: I had to dig deep into the comments of rc5 to find this mentioned. Weird that this requirement isn't listed more prominently on the website.